# How to run a JS widget on a tumblr sub-page

Tags: javascript, twitter, widget, toggle, tumblr

I'd like to add a twitter-list widget to one sub-page only.

On the one hand, the sub-pages HTML editor doesn't run JS, so entering the widget code there won't work.

On the other hand, I don't know how to enter the code in the theme HTML, but only show it on one page.

Should I give up and just use a redirect page?

Thanks.

Comment: You can add scripts to a single page, in the HTML editor, as long as you make a custom page. It should work. Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Actually any page will take custom js, but you have to entire it via the html editor.

Comment: I have tried using the custom age and the html editor, and it turns into a link or a redirect. Fooling around with it now. 

I've also tried to put the code into the theme HTML with a meta and a block, like with Google analytics and Disqus, or at least, that seems like what you have to do. Haven't gotten that right yet either. 

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Proof https://imgur.com/yERsdCd

Comment: Ha, here's my proof: http://covu-test.tumblr.com/test that is the only page on that tumblr that has the tweet link on it.

Comment: I've also served a second remote js file on that page that turns the body red. But only on that page. You can't see the js running in the tumblr preview page, you have to save your changes and then run the page in the browser.

Comment: I've posted an answer below. You might have to post some code that you have tried, or link to the tumblr, it's then possible to inspect the page for potential errors.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comments.

It is possible to add custom js to a single page, or post in tumblr using the html editor.

The code I have added looks like this:

```
<p>Content</p>
<p><a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share"> Tweet </a></p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
window.twttr=(function(d,s,id){var t,js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(d.getElementById(id)){return}js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);return window.twttr||(t={_e:[],ready:function(f){t._e.push(f)}})}(document,"script","twitter-wjs"));
// ]]></script>
<script src="http://slackwise.cfmldeveloper.com/jstests/scripts/bg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The content of the second js file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

   $('body').css('background-color','#FF0000');
   console.log('remote file served');

});
```

This js will only run on one page. In this case a test page I made on one of my tumblr accounts (see comments above).

In addition Tumblr will not run external javascript in preview mode. You have to save the content and tun the page in the browser.